# Why body is empty object, Express server, method post (2020)

Tags: node.js, express, post, fetch

I have simple server:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || "8080";

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to requests on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  console.log("»>", req.body)
});
```

send request from localhost:3000

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/', {
  "method": "post",
  "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "mode": "cors",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "body": JSON.stringify({"1":"sss"})
});
```

It's works, but req.body is {} - why? Any suggestions.

Comment: {} typically means empty object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the configuration of `fetch` wrong.

Request headers go in the `headers` property.

Since you put your `Content-Type` in the wrong place, you are sending a request with `Content-Type: text/plain` (the default for string bodies) so the JSON body parser ignores it (and you don't have a raw body parser set up).

(Aside, `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` starts with `Access` and is a **response** header, it has no place being on the request).

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/', {
  "method": "post",
  "mode": "cors",
  headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  "body": JSON.stringify({"1":"sss"})
});
```

---

Once you fix that, you get the expected error message for an improper CORS configuration. You've only set up your endpoint to handle simple requests, but JSON formatted requests are preflighted. The documentation for the `cors` module for express [explains how to configure it for preflighted requests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight).